# How to give an implicit sort to this Scala class?

Tags: scala

```
case class Point(x:Int, y:Int)  

class Scatterplot(arr: ArrayBuffer[Point]){
    val arrayOfNums = arr.sorted //no implicit ordering defined!
}
```

So far there is not much in my class, but I'd like to be able to sort `arr`. Is there a way I'd be able to set `arrayOfNums` to `arr.sorted`? I am not sure how to tell Scala to treat a Point `(x,y)` as a tuple, basically, which has implied ordering already.

And my second question: If I had an ArrayBuffer of Scatterplots, how could I give that implied sort ordering as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Point` doesn't literally have an "implied ordering" in any sense the compiler will recognize. It's pretty easy to provide one, though:

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)

object Point {
  implicit val pointOrdering: Ordering[Point] = Ordering.by {
    case Point(x, y) => (x, y)
  }
}
```

This provides the lexicographic ordering by saying that you want to map points to `(Int, Int)` (which does have an ordering instance) and compare those. If you want another ordering you can adjust the implementation appropriately.

Note that putting the ordering instance for `Point` in `Point`'s companion object ensures that it will be available even if you haven't imported `pointOrdering` into scope explicitly.

To answer your follow-up question: you can use similar code for `Scatterplot` once you have an ordering for `Point`:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

class Scatterplot(arr: ArrayBuffer[Point]){
  val arrayOfNums = arr.sorted
}

object Scatterplot {
  implicit val scatterplotOrdering: Ordering[Scatterplot] =
    Ordering.Implicits.seqDerivedOrdering[ArrayBuffer, Point].on[Scatterplot](
      _.arrayOfNums
    )
}
```

Sorting on a mutable collection is an even worse idea than sorting a mutable collection, though.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not quite sure what you mean by that last part (what is meant by available even if I have't imported it into scope explicitly?). And do you happen to know how to apply the sort on the second question?

Comment: Updated to answer the second question. The first is related to details of implicit resolution that probably deserve a separate question—the short answer is that putting these basic type class instances in the companion object is a best practice.

Comment: As opposed to putting them directly in the case class or something similar?

Comment: Also, "Sorting on a mutable collection is an even worse idea than sorting a mutable collection, though." what?

Comment: Nice answer, but I'd order by distance from (0, 0) first, then x and y.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Any particular reason?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Yeah, the question is underspecified so I just gave the simplest implementation (lexicographic ordering) and noted how to change it.

Comment: @ArukaJ If you sort on a mutable collection then the way the same object sorts could change (because you can change the object), which might cause surprising behaviour for other things. E.g. imagine having a `TreeSet` of `Scatterplot`s `A B C` (in order) and then changing `A` so that it now comes after `C` - the `TreeSet` wouldn't update itself, so if you called `set.from(B)` you wouldn't get `A` even though `A` now comes after `B`. You might even corrupt the internal representation of the `TreeSet`.